# How to place javascript code inside a php string

Tags: javascript, php, fwrite

I am using fwrite to add javascript to a external script. In order to do this there needs to be a php string with the java inside. However the " and ' get mixed up and I am not sure how to fix it. Here Is the code:

```
$page = 
"<script type="text/javascript"> 

function outf(text) { 
    var mypre = document.getElementById("output"); 
    mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text; 
} 
function builtinRead(x) {
    if (Sk.builtinFiles === undefined || Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x] === undefined)
    throw "File not found: '" + x + "'";
    return Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x];
}

function runit() { 
    var prog = document.getElementById("yourcode").value; 
    var mypre = document.getElementById("output"); 
    mypre.innerHTML = ''; 
    Sk.canvas = "mycanvas";
    Sk.pre = "output";
    Sk.configure({output:outf, read:builtinRead}); 
try {
    eval(Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>",false,prog)); 
}
catch(e) {
    alert(e.toString())
}
} 
</script> 
<?php
fwrite($fh, $page); ?>
```

The Script does what I want it to do, however the speech marks within the javascript mix with the php string speech marks as you can see above, causing the php to throw an error. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Escape your "s like this: \", or if you think that is dirty you can replace your "s with 's in your JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$page = 
"<script type=\"text/javascript\"> 

function outf(text) { 
    var mypre = document.getElementById(\"output\"); 
    mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text; 
} 
function builtinRead(x) {
    if (Sk.builtinFiles === undefined || Sk.builtinFiles[\"files\"][x] === undefined)
    throw \"File not found: '\" + x + \"'\";
    return Sk.builtinFiles[\"files\"][x];
}

function runit() { 
    var prog = document.getElementById(\"yourcode\").value; 
    var mypre = document.getElementById(\"output\"); 
    mypre.innerHTML = ''; 
    Sk.canvas = \"mycanvas\";
    Sk.pre = \"output\";
    Sk.configure({output:outf, read:builtinRead}); 
try {
    eval(Sk.importMainWithBody(\"<stdin>\",false,prog)); 
}
catch(e) {
    alert(e.toString())
}
} 
</script>";

<?php
fwrite($fh, $page); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use here doc like so:

```
$page = <<<EOF
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    .....enter the rest of the code here...
    </script>
EOF;

echo $page;
```

find a manual to learn how to use heredoc

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

1. Replace all the double quotes in your javascript with single quotes
2. Escape all the quotes as Andreas mentioned
3. Use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Personally, I would go for #3

Answer (score 1):

Use `"''"`, or `'""'`, or `"\"\" "` to escape the strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way which is some kind comfortable and beautiful for you will keep overview, syntax highlighting and don't have to fight with the quotes:

```
<?php
ob_start(); // start output buffering
?> <!-- mark that there is no more php following, but HTML -->
<!-- copy your js here (without the very first quotes) -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function outf(text) { 
    var mypre = document.getElementById("output"); 
    mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text; 
} 
// ............
</script>
<?php
$script = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
fwrite($fh, $script);
```

this will write your js to the file